# How well $\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor + (x-\lfloor \sqrt{x}\rfloor^2)(2\lfloor \sqrt{x}\rfloor)^{-1}$ approximate $\sqrt{x}$?

Tags: approximation, ceiling-and-floor-functions, square-numbers

How well $\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor + \dfrac{x-\lfloor \sqrt{x}\rfloor^2}{2\lfloor \sqrt{x}\rfloor}$ approximate $\sqrt{x}$ ?

After some searching, I found this interesting formula. It can be shown easily that for $x$ a square number this formula will always work.

I don't know how well it is actually approximating the square root. With a graph, this formula seems to fit quite well with the square root. Especially for very large values or very close to square numbers.

And also, when this formula create the worst approximation ?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: I cannot see a formula in your question.

Comment: Oh okay, i'm talking about this : $\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor + \dfrac{x-\lfloor \sqrt{x}\rfloor^2}{2\lfloor \sqrt{x}\rfloor}$.

Comment: This is the first iterate of Newton's method when the initial approximation is $\lfloor\sqrt x\rfloor$. The largest error occurs at the end of every unit interval.

Comment: This is not a formula (=a mathematical relationship or rule expressed in symbols.) Please be more precise.

Comment: @vitamind: I do see a formula, and it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Sorry, I am french. I will use the same word in french. I am sorry.

Comment: @YvesDaoust "How well $\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor + \dfrac{x-\lfloor \sqrt{x}\rfloor^2}{2\lfloor \sqrt{x}\rfloor}$ approximate $\sqrt{x}$" is not a formula. It's a question. The expressions used are terms. Anyways, it is more or less clear what the OP is trying to ask, so (+1) to your comment.

Comment: @vitamind: $\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor + \dfrac{x-\lfloor \sqrt{x}\rfloor^2}{2\lfloor \sqrt{x}\rfloor}$ is undisputably a formula. It is not an equation and it is an expression.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Oh, I see ! I didn't see it was linked with Newton's method. Thanks !

Comment: You might be interested in the approximation of $\sqrt{N}=\sqrt{a^2+b}\approx \left(a+\frac b{2a}\right)-\frac{\left(\frac b{2a}\right)^2}{2\left(a+\frac b{2a}\right)}$ I developped in this post https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2866233/399263 and which also is an application of one iteration of Newton's method but formulated slightly differently.

Comment: It's actually kind of crummy for $0<x<1$. Use a downward extrapolation from the ceiling value to get better results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, the formula only makes sense when $x\ge1$ (since $\lfloor\sqrt x\rfloor=0$ for $0\le x\lt1$). Now let $\lfloor\sqrt x\rfloor=\sqrt x-r$ with $0\le r\lt1$. Then

$$\begin{align}
\lfloor\sqrt x\rfloor+{x-\lfloor\sqrt x\rfloor^2\over2\lfloor\sqrt x\rfloor}
&=(\sqrt x-r)+{x-(\sqrt x-r)^2\over2(\sqrt x-r)}\\
&=(\sqrt x-r)+{2r\sqrt x-r^2\over2(\sqrt x-r)}\\
&=\sqrt x+{r^2\over2(\sqrt x-r)}\\
&=\sqrt x+{r^2\over2\lfloor\sqrt x\rfloor}
\end{align}$$

So we see that the error term is always non-negative (i.e., the formula always somewhat overestimates the actual square root), and always less than $1/2$ (which it approaches as $x\to4^-$). It is quadratically small when $r\approx0$ (i.e., when $x$ is slightly larger than a square integer), and close to $1/(2\sqrt x)$ when $x$ is slightly less than a square integer, which itself is small when $x$ is large. As noted, the approximation is worst when $x$ is slightly smaller than $4$.